# Exception thrown when running asp.net core application on Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0, dotnet-cli, cakebuild

I have an Ubuntu VM which `publishes` an ASP.Net Core application 2.0 with CakeBuild .

The output is then moved to another Ubuntu VM where .Net Core SDK already installed.

When I try to `dotnet` the main dll file, the following exception is thrown:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This is my `build.cake`

```
Task("Clean")
.Does(() =>
{
   CleanDirectory(binaryDir);
   CleanDirectory(objectDir);
   CleanDirectory(publishDir);
});

Task("Restore")
.IsDependentOn("Clean")
.Does(() =>
{
   DotNetCoreRestore(solutionPath);
});

Task("Build")
.IsDependentOn("Restore")
.Does(() => {
   var settings = new DotNetCorePublishSettings
   {
      Configuration = configuration, // Release
      OutputDirectory = publishDir,
      Runtime = runtime // linux-x64
   };

   DotNetCorePublish(solutionPath, settings);
});
```

In the application I am using two nuget packages which were published from a Windows machine (.Net Standard 2.0), will this cause `dotnet` to fail ? if yes, how to use nuget packages which are Linux compatible ?

## Temp Solution

For now I am building the application using the native dotnet CLI `publish` command which is doing the trick; but that means for now cake build is useless for my case here (until the problem is fixed of course).

Comment: It'll sound like a silly question, but do the versions of the runtimes match up? If you run `dotnet --version` on both VMs, do you get the same output?

Comment: Both were installed at the same time, so they are `2.0.2` which is the latest.

Comment: Huh. That's really quite strange.

Comment: Which version of Cake are you using?

Comment: Latest I suppose, I just call `build.sh` and it downloads the binaries.

Comment: @Ayman If you run your build script with diagnostic verbosity `--verbosity=diagnostic` and compare the invocation of `dotnet restore` to how you invoke `dotnet publish` manually, is there a difference? Can you also output `dotnet --version` in your bootstrapper script before running to verify that it's using the correct SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With further investigation, I found that providing the `output` or the `runtime` parameters as full names causes the issue ([bug #8298](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/8298)), so I don't think it's a Cake issue, but rather they invoke the `DotNetCorePublish` command with full name arguments.

[cake/src/Cake.Common/Tools/DotNetCore/Publish/DotNetCorePublisher.cs lines 63-75](https://github.com/cake-build/cake/blob/develop/src/Cake.Common/Tools/DotNetCore/Publish/DotNetCorePublisher.cs#L63)

```
// Output directory
if (settings.OutputDirectory != null)
{
    builder.Append("--output");
    builder.AppendQuoted(settings.OutputDirectory.MakeAbsolute(_environment).FullPath);
}

// Runtime
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.Runtime))
{
    builder.Append("--runtime");
    builder.Append(settings.Runtime);
}
```